# Is Genesis 1:27 same event as in Genesis 2:22?

Tags: genesis, hebrew

Is Genesis 1:27 same event as in Genesis 2:22. Are the both account about Adam being made?

> So God created man in his own image, in the image of God created he
> him; male and female created he them. **(Genesis 1:27 - KJV)**

> And the rib, which the Lord God had taken from man, made he a woman,
> and brought her unto the man. **(Genesis 2:22 - KJV)**

There are those that claim that Adam (אדם H120) in Gen 1:27 is referring to mankind being made. The two events looks at the surface to speak of two different event Gen 1 both man and female was made at once but in Gen 2 then in Gen 2:7 Adam is made and further down women is introduced in Gen 2:22.

They that claim it's two different account, Mankind Vs Adam they us this as "proof" (to me it's no proof but a very good argument) that's the reason Cain feared being killed when he was expelled from the garden;

> Behold, thou hast driven me out this day from the face of the earth;
> and from thy face shall I be hid; and I shall be a fugitive and a
> vagabond in the earth; and it shall come to pass, ***that every one
> that findeth me shall slay me***. **(Genesis 4:14 - KJV)**

Answer (score 4):

They are the same event.

- Gen 1:26, 27 describes the creation of the first male and female humans in outline only.
- Gen 2:16-24 describes the same event in greater detail.

While Adam and eve were placed in Eden to tend and cultivate it (Gen 2:15), they were later banished because of their sin (Gen 3:23, 24).

**APPENDIX - Descendants of Adam and Eve**

The progeny of Adam and Eve are listed below (see Gen 3:20)

- Cain, Gen 4:1
- Abel, Gen 4:2
- Seth. Gen 4:25

Abel was murdered, but Cain and Seth (and their progeny) became the prototypes of unfaithful and faithful followers of God.

Comment: Thanks Dottard for your contribution!

Answer (score 3):

Were the זָכָ֥ר Zakar (male) & נְקֵבָ֖ה Neqevah (female) of הָֽאָדָם Ha-Adam (Humanity) in [Bereshit 1:27] -- the same beings as the אִ֖ישׁ Ish (Man) & אִשָּׁה Ishah (Woman) of הָֽאָדָם Ha-Adam in [Bereshit 2:22]?

No. - Ish & Ishah were enlightened beings, chosen to guard all life in גַן עֵ֔דֶן Gan Eden (Garden [of] Eden) as stated in Bereshit 2:15.

**When Does Torah teach us that the enlightened Ish & Ishah (named: אָדָ֥ם "Adam" & חַוָּ֣ה "Chavah") were different beings from the זָכָ֥ר Zakar (male) & נְקֵבָ֖ה Neqevah (female) of [Bereshit 1:27]?**

- In [Bereshit 4:16] - We are told the son of Adam & Chavah went from the presence of HaShem to marry a נ֖וֹד Nod (Wanderer).

"Qayin left the presence of YHVH and settled in the-land [of] Nod, east of Eden." ( וַיֵּ֥צֵא קַ֖יִן מִלִּפְנֵ֣י יְהֹוָ֑ה וַיֵּ֥שֶׁב בְּאֶֽרֶץ־נ֖וֹד קִדְמַת־עֵֽדֶן )

**We learn in [Bereshit 4:17] that one נְקֵבָ֖ה Neqevah (female) of נ֖וֹד Nod became Qayin's wife אִשְׁתּ֔וֹ - and was not a descendant of Chavah & Adam.**

"Qayin knew [his-wife], and she conceived and bore Chanok. And he then founded a city, and named the city after his-son Chanok." ( וַיֵּ֤דַע קַ֙יִן֙ אֶת־אִשְׁתּ֔וֹ וַתַּ֖הַר וַתֵּ֣לֶד אֶת־חֲנ֑וֹךְ וַֽיְהִי֙ בֹּ֣נֶה עִ֔יר וַיִּקְרָא֙ שֵׁ֣ם הָעִ֔יר כְּשֵׁ֖ם בְּנ֥וֹ חֲנֽוֹךְ )

**Torah makes the distinction that the ancestors of Qayin's wife (from Nod) were not descendants of Adam & Chavah. | Which means Ha-Adam of Nod were the זָכָ֥ר Zakar (male) & נְקֵבָ֖ה Neqevah (female) created in [Bereshit 1:27].**

**However — The Book of [Jubilees] claims Qayin (Cain) married his sister named און “Avan”.**

[Jubilees 4:1] “And in the third week in the second jubilee she gave birth to Cain, and in the fourth she gave birth to Abel, and in the fifth she gave birth to her daughter ’Âwân.” ( ובשבוע השלישי ליובל השני ילדה את קין וברביעי ילדה את הבל ובחמישי ילדה את בתה און )

[Jubilees 4:11] “And Cain took ’Âwân his sister to be his wife and she bare him Enoch at the close of the fourth jubilee.” ( ויקח קין את אחותו און לו לאשה ותלד לו את חנוך מקץ היובל הרביעי )

[Source: https://www.sefaria.org/Book_of_Jubilees.4.11?lang=bi&with=Translations&lang2=en]

Comment: Thanks! Can you elaborate on your answer with references to midrash or other sources?

Comment: @חִידָה Thanks a lot Chidah!! I didn't see אִ֖ישׁ  in Gen 2:22 but אִ֖ישׁ occur once in v23 & v24. Cain Gen 4:16 "dwelt in the land of Nod" 17 "And Cain knew his wife; and she conceived, and bare Enoch:" Yes its this teori I have heard but were do we see נְקֵבָ֖ה female again in Gen 4?

Comment: "one נְקֵבָ֖ה Neqevah (female) of נ֖וֹד Nod became Qayin's wife אִשְׁתּ֔וֹ - and was not a descendant of Chavah & Adam. / Torah makes the distinction that the ancestors of Qayin's wife (from Nod) were not descendants of Adam & Chavah." This is a strong claim. How do you know this? Please edit to explain the evidence.

Comment: @curiousdannii - See updated source.

Comment: Isn't that evidence against your claim? I'm confused.

Comment: @curiousdannii - I have provided two answers. One from Bereshit, One from Jubilees.

Comment: Okay. So where is the evidence for your claim that "Torah makes the distinction that the ancestors of Qayin's wife (from Nod) were not descendants of Adam & Chavah."

Answer (score 3):

Very interesting topic/question. At dinner we had the same discussion. At one point my son who is a researcher with a PhD said that science has proven that all of humanity came from one mother. (Eve) However reading Genesis 1:27 and Genesis 2:22 seem like two different and separate events.

The problem we many times face is that for years we base our beliefs on our own and other people's assumptions. For instance many times we are told (or we may have told others) that for a period of time after Creation Hashem allowed incest in order to kick start populating earth. On the other hand why would Hashem tell Adam and Eve to be fruitful and multiply? However there is nowhere stating that incest is NO LONGER allowed other than Leviticus 18.

I would like to see more answers and direction to this interesting question.

Answer (score 1):

Is Genesis 1:27 same event as in Genesis 2:22. Are the both account about Adam being made?

Yes to the first half of the question and I will explain further down.

Also like many of us questioned who are these people that he is afraid of that might slay him?

> and it shall come to pass, that every one that findeth me shall slay me. (Genesis 4:14 - KJV)

It was very easy to be distracted by not having any specific scripture to who these people were. The only reference of Adam and Eves other children was mentioned in one verse.

> Genesis 5:5 Adam lived 800 years and had other sons and daughters.

Hard to imagine why so many of these people would've left their parents Adam and Eve and the Lord's presence and go somewhere else.  And they would've had to have left before Cain killed Abel.  One can only speculate.  These had to be the people that Cain was afraid of.

I to have read other scenarios that seem pretty far-fetched but incredibly interesting.

It was through Seth's seed that  would continue to the line of Christ that was mentioned.

Now getting back to the first half of your question.

Is Genesis 1:27 same event as in Genesis 2:22. Are the both account about Adam being made?

What is so different between these two scriptures.  Here's what I see.

God speaks forth his word in Genesis1:27

Here's some examples taken from Genesis one.

And God saith...,

It's about 30 times in Genesis1 where it says and God say it has something is created:

> 3 And God saith, ‘Let light be;
> 5and God calleth
> 6 And God saith
> 7And God maketh
> 8 And God calleth
> 9  God saith

If you continue to read the whole chapter you'll see that it always says God Speaking.

Then someone else is brought into the picture.  Us

This is very telling as it is showing the relationship between God the Father  and His Son together creating man.
And he brings up their image And their likeness before he man is created.

> 6And God saith, ‘Let Us make man in Our image, according to Our likeness,
> Genesis 2:3

> 3And God ...He hath ceased from all His work which God had prepared for making.

So God is now finished with his work and now we here for  the first time Jehovah God

Remember what it says in

> Isaiah 55:11 It is the same with my word. I send it out, and it always produces fruit. It will accomplish all I want it to, and it will prosper everywhere I send it.

Keep this in mind now as Jehovah God accomplishes the words that were spoken in Genesis 1 by God.

> Genesis 2:4 It's now Jehovah God who Accomplishes the word that he was sent to do.

These [are] births of the heavens and of the earth in their being prepared, in the day of Jehovah God’s making earth and heavens;

> Genesis two
> 4 Jehovah God hath not rained upon the earth,
> 7 And Jehovah God formeth the man — dust from the ground, and breatheth into his nostrils breath of life, and the man becometh a living creature.
> 8 Jehovah God planteth a garden in Eden, at the east, and He setteth there the man whom He hath formed;
> 9 Jehovah God causeth to sprout from the ground every tree desirable for appearance,
> 15 Jehovah God causeth to sprout from the ground every tree desirable for appearance,
> 16 And Jehovah God layeth a charge on the man, saying, ‘Of every tree of the garden eating thou dost eat;
> 18 And Jehovah God saith, ‘Not good for the man to be alone, I do make to him an helper — as his counterpart
> 19 Jehovah God formeth from the ground every beast of the field
> 21 nd Jehovah God causeth a deep sleep to fall upon the man
> 22 Jehovah God buildeth up the rib which He hath taken out of the man into a woman, and bringeth her in unto the man

The woman is hidden inside the man.

Here's a great prophetic message That is revealed more in

> Ephesians 5:32. "For this cause shall a man leave his father and mother, and shall be joined to his wife, and they shall be — the two — for one flesh;’ 32this secret is great, and I speak in regard to Christ and to the assembly

> 25 Adam again knoweth his wife, and she beareth a son, and calleth his name Seth, ‘for God hath appointed for me another seed instead of Abel:’ for Cain had slain him. 26And to Seth, to him also a son hath been born, and he calleth his name Enos; then a beginning was made of preaching in the name of Jehovah.

So I conclude that genesis 1:27 and 2:22 Go hand-in-hand.

It is God first and then the Son doing everything he sees the father doing.

> 15The Son is the image of the invisible God, the firstborn over all creation. 16For in Him all things were created, things in heaven and on earth, visible and invisible, whether thrones or dominions or rulers or authorities. All things were created through Him and for Him.

> 1 Corinthians 8:6
> yet for us there is but one God, the Father, from whom all things came and for whom we exist. And there is but one Lord, Jesus Christ, through whom all things came and through whom we exist.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution Sherrie +1. The thing with the daughter teori, yes the mating part would make sens that the first humans on earth would mate siblings, but would they leave Garden Eden for Nod and would he fear his baby-sisters to kill him? for if they left before him they are only women no men. "The woman is hidden inside the man" the rib was his rib not a women but his rib was made to a women, have to disagree that women was hidden in man.

Comment: Hi Daniel, Adam had other SON'S  and daughters.  Genesis 5:4 .  God has blessed Adam and Eve to be fruitful and multiply.  G 1:28 Perhaps they left home to start their own family as it says a man leaves his father and mother and is united to his wife. G 2:24
Cain's fear  could be self imposed.  A consequence of sin bringing fear and death.   God created them male and female.   It was the Lord God who took out of Adam's body bone that had the makings of woman.  Reminds me of Michelangelo who said 
Every block of stone has a statue inside it and it is the task of the sculptor to discover it.

Comment: Well he might have more son's after Seth but Cain was the first son and after that Abel which Cain killed. That's why it feels like two sets of people was made, Cain even builds a city after Nod so it seems Nod was a population to recon with.

Comment: Daniel,  I totally agree with you that it feels like two sets of people.  Studying  this out was labor-intensive along with much frustration on what was not said or revealed.
This morning I was reminded of this verse in Acts 17:26
From ONE MAN He made every nation of men, that they should inhabit the whole earth; 
It was only through Adam's children that the other nations were formed. It was through Seth that the nation of Israel came into being along with the seed of the woman that became Christ.  Thanks for bringing this question up as it is finally settled it for me.

Comment: I don't have "From ONE MAN He made every nation of men" but KJV read; of one blood all nations of men. if they are two sets of people then they in Gen 1:27 God said, Let us make man in our image, after our **likeness** can have same blood, maybe it was a way for God to avoid incest. But Book of Jubilees say both Cain and Seth marry their sisters, Cain took Âwân his sister to be his wife,  Seth took ’Azûrâ his sister [Jubilees Ch4](http://www.pseudepigrapha.com/jubilees/4.htm)

Comment: Daniel,  The point is whether it's from one man, one blood or just from one the meaning is still the same.  It's from ONE that every nation of men dwell on the face of the earth.  Another possibility is that Cain had A wife before he left for Nod.  (One of his relatives) then Cain went out from the presence of the Lord and dwelt in the land of Nod on the east of Eden. And Cain knew his wife, and she conceived and bore Enoch. Gen. 4:16-17. It is so hard to fill in the blanks when we just have a few Scriptures with gaps in them.

Comment: If you see Jubillees as scripture then it plain and clear; Cain took Âwân his sister to be his wife, Seth took ’Azûrâ his sister